# How to handle long api requests when loading view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api

I'm working on a rails app that displays user content. In one of my controllers #show action I do an api call to generate recommendations for "up next" content. This api call takes about 5 seconds for a response, not ridiculously long, but too long to make the user wait before loading the page.

The recommendations themselves don't appear until the users have scrolled 2/3 of the way down the page so they don't need to be there when the page is initially loaded.

My question, is there a good way to load the rest of the pages content and wait to load just that section of the page until the api call is finished and the recommendations are ready? Thanks in advance!

## Controller

```
class DiscoverEmailsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @discover_email = DiscoverEmail.find_by(message_id: params[:message_id])

    #just in development for now
    @up_next = Rails.env.development?
        #API call that takes too long to wait for
        up_next_ids = RecommendationsHelper.get_one_step_recommendations(@discover_email.subject, @discover_email.preview, @discover_email.senders_name)

        up_next_ids.each do |message_id_and_score|
            break if @up_next.length >= 4

            discover_email = DiscoverEmail.find_by(message_id: message_id_and_score[1])

            unless discover_email.nil?
                @up_next << discover_email unless discover_email.image_url.nil? || discover_email.senders_name.nil? || discover_email.subject.nil?
            end
        end
    else
        @up_next = DiscoverEmail.where.not(senders_name: nil, image_url: nil, subject: nil).order(date: :desc).last(4)
    end

    DiscoverEmail.track_view(email_address, @discover_email)
  end
end
```

## View Body

```
  <body class="iframe-page">

<h3 class="email-subject"><%= @discover_email.subject %></h3>

<div class="iframe-content">
  <iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups" src="<%= @url %>" allowfullscreen></iframe>


     #Section I'd like to wait to load since it's hidden until users are most of the way down the page 
  <div id="discover-up-next">
    <div id="up-next-border">
      <div class="border-lines"></div>
      <p id="up-next-text">NEXT UP</p>
      <div class="border-lines"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="up-next-cells" style="display: inline-flex; height: 110px;">
      <% @up_next.each_with_index do |discover_email, index| %>
        <% if discover_email.subscription.clearbit_logo_url.nil? || discover_email.subscription.clearbit_logo_url == "noclearbitlogo" %>
        <%      logo_safe = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myblendappimages/blend_logo_mashup_pattern_80.png" %>
        <% elsif discover_email.subscription.clearbit_logo_url.include? "http://logo.clearbit.com/"%>
        <%      logo_safe = discover_email.subscription.clearbit_logo_url %>
        <% else %>
        <%      logo_safe = "http://logo.clearbit.com/" + discover_email.subscription.clearbit_logo_url %>
        <% end %>

        <% subject = discover_email.fit_subject %>

        <div id="recommendation-<%= index + 1 %>" style="height: 110px; width: 320px;">
          <% unless index == 0 %>
          <div class="left-line" >
          <% end %>
          <div class="up-next-cell">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="discover-up-next-cell-text col-xs-8" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px; text-align: left;">
                <%= link_to subject, discover_show_path(message_id: discover_email.message_id), class: "up-next-cell-subject" %>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                  <div class="gallery_card_logo col-sm-2 col-xs-3 no-padding" style="width: 20px !important; margin-right: 5px;">
                    <%= image_tag(logo_safe, style: "width: 20px; height: 20px; float: left;") %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-9 no-padding">
                    <p class="discover-up-next-senders-name"><%= discover_email.senders_name %></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <%= link_to(image_tag(discover_email.image_url, class: "discover-email-up-next-cell-image"), discover_show_path(message_id: discover_email.message_id)) %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <% unless index == 0 %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with a combo of javascript/ajax and ruby.

## ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  #use ajax to call controller action AFTER page finishes loading
  $(window).load(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/discover/up_next",
      cache: false,
      data: {"random": "data"},
      success: function(html){
        $("#discover-up-next-container").append(html);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

## ruby controller action called by ajax

```
def up_next
  wait = Wait.new
  @up_next = #get up next content

  #wait until content is ready to load html
  wait.until { @up_next.empty? == false }
  render layout: false
end
```